# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Undefinded Property

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have a Model `House` and a Model `energy_class`.

A house has only one energy class. Energy Classes can be assigned to multiple houses. I therefore defined the relationships like this:

House.php

```
class House extends Model
{
    public function energy_class()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\energy_class', 'id', 'energy_class');
    }
}
```

energy_class.php

```
class energy_class extends Model
{
    public function house()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\House');
    }
}
```

When passing the House Data to a view like this:

```
$house = House::with('energy_class')->find($id);
return view('admin.houses.edit')->with('house', $house);
```

And referencing it on the view like this:

```
$house->energy_class()->name
```

I get this error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$name`

When doing it like this: `$house->energy_class->name` I get `trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Can you show the names of the tables and the column names for the database.

Comment: Tables: `house`, `energy_classes`. Columns: `house.energy_class`, `energy_classes.name`

Answer (score 2):

Your first suggestion:

```
$house->energy_class()->name
```

Does not work, because at this point you only called the relationship, you didn't yet specify from it what you wanted, e.g.:

```
$house->energy_class()->first()
```

Your second try returns empty because $house->energy_class (which does the same as the above code), didn't return any results.

There can be various causes for this:

- Your relationship is not properly signed up
- Your database is not properly setup (have you set up a foreign key in your migration?)
- The house actually does not have an energy class filled out

I suspect in your case it might be the second or the third. Could you paste me your migration script?

Edit: PS. if this error occurs because perhaps not each house actually has a an energy class, you could use the following code to check for this:

```
$house->energy_class ? $house->energy_class->name : "No energy class available";
```

Comment: Here is the part of the migration: `$table->integer('energy_class')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('energy_class')->references('id')->on('energy_classes');` The house I am trying to edit has the energy class with id 1 set which refers to a class with the name `A++`

Comment: `$house->energy_class()->first()->name` is working. But shouldnt it be possible without `first()` Because the relationship should tell laravel that there is only one related record...

Comment: It's odd that $house->energy_class->name is not working, but your suggestion does work. Happy to hear you have the information you need thought! The reason that you still have to ask for first, is because there are various other options (e.g, firstOrFail, firstOrCreate) available.